# Imitate search engine header in browser

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, safari, safari-extension

I'm using Google Chrome and Apple Safari as browser. I would like to see websites like search engines would - since I sometimes experience that I am being treated differently as a "real human" rather than what a search engine would be served.

Is there a way to do that in Chrome and/or Safari? Possibly with an extension?

Answer (score 0):

You could spoof your user agent. [User-Agent Switcher for Chrome](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/user-agent-switcher-for-c/djflhoibgkdhkhhcedjiklpkjnoahfmg) is a good extension for this. Just do a google search for the user agent of your chosen search robot and enter that, and sites should think you're a robot.